# How to make sure only one thread is executing background context block

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

In my application, I've got a background thread which make sure the local database (core data) is synchronized with server. There are multiple ways to trigger the processing (notificationServer observer, timer, ...). However, I want to make sure there is only one instance processing the data at the time. So, if a processing task is triggered while "old" synchronization task is running, I want it to wait for the previous task to finish.

My current code looks something like this:

```
backgroundContext = persistance.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
// this is an instance variable which will be shared by all the threads
...
...
@objc func managedObjectContextDidSave(notification: NSNotification) {
        backgroundContext.perform {
            self.processAllHisotory()
        }
}
```

Is it guaranteed that if I perform multiple tasks on the same context, they will not get executed in parallel? If not, what is the best way to synchronize such tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a DispatchQueue, it is a serial queue. A new task cannot start while a task is in progress. In effect, the serial queue is a lock.

Comment: Thanks. Make sense. My understanding is that ManagedObjectContext uses a DispatchQueue under the scenes - so, what I'm doing should be sufficient. One more thing I need to do is to be able to wait() for the processing to finish in the case it's running. Any idea how to do that other then somehing like managedObjectContext.performAndWait() { noop() }?